# How to generate 2d canvas from console to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

My code I have so far will generate into console.log. When I hit F12 it will display an img right there in the console.

How can I make it appear inside a div or somewhere more user appropriate than the console?

I tried making a `<div class = "mylog">` to appropriate it inside canvas but I'm new sure how to code that together either.

Any suggestions & help would be super awesome!

I hope my question is straight forward.

```
(function(console) {
  console.image = function(url) {   
    var image = document.createElement('img'),
    canvas    = document.createElement('canvas'),

    canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d'),

//more code here//

    })(console);
        window.onload = function() {

          console.image()
);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We will need to see more code to be any help because it seems that you're directly placing the function inside the console as an image. This gets rendered as 2d, and a canvas but will output only to console. You need to redo the code or show us more context to give you a better idea of what to change.